# Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$, how do elements of $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ give a map $V^*\rightarrow V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

An article I'm reading claims that if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field $k$, and $f\in \text{Sym}^2(V)$, then $f$ induces a morphism $V^*\rightarrow V$, where $V^*$ denotes the dual space.

If we let $x_1,\ldots,x_r$ be a basis of $V$, then we can write $f = \sum_{i\le j}a_{ij}x_ix_j$, and given $\varphi\in V^*$, one could try to consider the map
$$\varphi\mapsto \sum_{i\le j}a_{ij}\varphi(x_i)x_j\in V$$
but surely this isn't well defined...

EDIT: This is the bottom of page 38 of [the stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/curves.pdf).

Comment: It seems like it should be a morphism from $V$ to $V^*$.

Comment: Your notation is horrendous. You're using $x_1,\dots,x_r$ both as basis vectors and as coordinates of a vector (presumably with respect that said basis). Please clean this up?

Comment: @TedShifrin Where have I used it as coordinates of a vector?

Comment: In the stacks project reference there is a matrix at the bottom on p. 38. The linear transformation you seek is the one with that matrix.

Comment: The source link says "for some $\kappa$-basis $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ of $V$", so I guess $V$ is finite dimensional. It would be good to mention that in the question.

Comment: @rtz When you write $f = \sum_{i\le j}a_{ij}x_ix_j$, it must be that the $x_i$ are scalars.  Otherwise, what does $x_ix_j$ mean?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $x_ix_j$ is the image of $x_i\otimes x_j$ in $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$. This makes sense if you identify polynomials function on $V^*$ with the symmetric algebra on $V$.

Comment: @stewbasic ah, thanks for that

Answer (score 3):

There is a tensor-hom adjunction $\hom(V,W)\cong V^\vee\otimes W$, where $\varphi\otimes w$ acts as a linear map $V\to W$ via the relation $(\varphi\otimes w)(v)=\varphi(v)w$.

Combining this with the natural isomorphism $V\to V^{\vee\vee}$ (for finite-dimensional $V$, otherwise it is simply a natural transformation), we have

$$ V^{\otimes 2}=V\otimes V\cong V^{\vee\vee}\otimes V\cong \hom(V^{\vee},V).$$

Thus, any tensor in $V^{\otimes 2}$ may be regarded as a linear map $V^{\vee}\to V$. Here's how: let $v_1\otimes v_2$ be an element of $V\otimes V$, then define $V^{\vee}\to V$ by $(v_1\otimes v_2)\varphi=\varphi(v_1)v_2$.

In particular, we may regard $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$ as the $S_2$-invariant subspace of $V^{\otimes 2}$, and so any element of $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$ induces a linear map $V^{\vee}\to V$.

If you regard $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$ as a quotient of $V^{\otimes 2}$ with elements written as sums of products $v_1v_2$, then the subspace and the quotient definitions are isomorphic via the symmetrization

$$ v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1 ~ \longleftrightarrow ~~ v_1v_2 $$

(up to scaling), in which case if you want to describe how to use elements of $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)$ as linear maps $V^{\vee}\to V$ with the quotient definition, we can simply write

$$ (v_1v_2)\varphi:=(v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1)\varphi=\varphi(v_1)v_2+\varphi(v_2)v_1. $$

Comment: I guess you meant to say $(v_1\otimes v_2)\varphi = \varphi(v_1)v_2 + \varphi(v_2)v_1$?

Comment: @rtz No. For $v_1\otimes v_2\in V\otimes V$, I mean $(v_1\otimes v_2)\varphi=\varphi(v_1)v_2$. If we regard ${\rm Sym}^2V$ as a subspace of $V^{\otimes 2}$ spanned by elements of the form $v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1$, then we do have $$(v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1)\varphi=\varphi(v_1)v_2+\varphi(v_2)v_1.  $$

Comment: But $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ is not a subspace of $V^{\otimes 2}$ - it's a quotient. Thus, the element $v_1\otimes v_2$ in $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ is equal to $v_2\otimes v_1$, and so the equation $(v_1\otimes v_2)\varphi = \varphi(v_1)v_2$ is not well defined if $v_1\otimes v_2$ represents an element of $\text{Sym}^2(V)$. Or perhaps I am confused?

Comment: @rtz In characteristic zero, ${\rm Sym}^d(V)$ can be defined as *either* a subspace of $V^{\otimes d}$ (of $S_d$-invariant elements) *or* as a quotient of $V^{\otimes d}$.

Comment: Isn't my objection still valid then? Viewing $\text{Sym}^2(V)$ as the quotient of $V^{\otimes 2}$, the map $(v_1\otimes v_2)\varphi \mapsto \varphi(v_1)v_2$ isn't well defined?

Comment: @rtz Your objection is not relevant to my comment or my answer because both say to regard ${\rm Sym}^2V$ as a subspace of $V^{\otimes 2}$, not as a quotient. BTW, I would write $v_1v_2$ for an element in the quotient definition, not $v_1\otimes v_2$. An isomorphism between the two versions (up to scaling) is given by $v_1v_2\leftrightarrow v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1$ (which is well-defined), in which case if you want to describe what's going on in the quotient definition you can simply write $$ (v_1v_2)\varphi=(v_1\otimes v_2+v_2\otimes v_1)\varphi=\varphi(v_1)v_2+\varphi(v_2)v_1. $$

Answer (score 2):

Define $f:V\otimes_KV\to\mathrm{Hom}_K(V^*,V)$ by
$$
  f(v\otimes w)(\phi)=\phi(v)w+\phi(w)v.
$$
This is clearly symmetric under $v\otimes w\mapsto w\otimes v$, so it factors to a map $\mathrm{Sym}^2(V)\to\mathrm{Hom}_K(V^*,V)$.

As Lord Shark the Unknown comments, the source link gives a matrix for the transformation using a basis for $V$. This can be verified to agree with the above.